# Why nuxt content fetch methods not working?

Tags: javascript, methods, fetch, nuxt.js

I am trying to fetch from content using methods like `only()`, `sort()` and etc and none of them work. When I try to fetch, it shows me nothing is found or I get an empty json:

```
message: "/blog/authors/authors not found"
```

[Original error image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6qPO.png)

And yes, I am sure that `Vivian` from search keyword is in the json of authors. Also this message appears on almost every method I use, not even in search.

This is the code I am trying to write:

```
async asyncData({query, $content, store, redirect,}) {
    const { selectedLocale } = store.state.blog;
    const posts = await $content(`blog/posts/${selectedLocale}`).search(query.key).fetch();
    ...
}
```

The fetch by itself works correctly and I get the data, though methods - not. Maybe somebody knows why I get errors like this and can't use fetching methods?

My json array looks it is written correctly:
[Author json image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkM8G.png)

Comment: Are you sure you have `/blog/authors/authors` file? From both pic, they are reference to 2 different things

Comment: Hi, I may be wrong but maybe you need to index the field you're searching? See [fullTextSearchFields docs](https://content.nuxtjs.org/configuration#fulltextsearchfields)

Comment: @bmartins sadly, this did not work for me :(

Comment: @zernonia I am sure that the path `/blog/authors/authors` is correct, I have checked it. The search is not working not only for authors, though for posts too, that's why I inserted different images, though srry for misleading info, will update the text in the post